# Placement of custom partition csv file

Tags: esp32

I need to create a custom csv file for my ESP32 project. Where would i need to place this file, as I am getting the following error message?

> Build files have been written to:
> G:/TestProjects/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/demos/projects/ESPRESSIF/esp32/build
> Running ninja in directory
> g:\testprojects\iot-middleware-freertos-samples\demos\projects\espressif\esp32\build
> Executing "ninja all"... ninja: error: '../partitions_IOT_A.csv',
> needed by 'partition_table/partition-table.bin', missing and no known
> rule to make it ninja failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message the csv file is expected to be one directory up from the build directory in `g:\testprojects\iot-middleware-freertos-samples\demos\projects\espressif\esp32\build`.

[ESP IDF documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html#creating-custom-tables) specifies that the partition table file needs to be in the root of the project directory.